# UPS turning off by itself every morning

Tags: ups

I have a UPS and a server connected to it.
It works well all day long, but something after midnight its leds start flashing and it does doing some noises, like "tec, tec" as a relay. And it continues increasing the speed between this until it completly turns off. It just can't support the server. After this I need to wait a few hours to make it work again, or it will turn off again.

What means this?

thank you.

Comment: What happens if you suddenly unplug the UPS? Be as specific as possible in decscribing what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Well, either your UPS is failing **or** you're putting a high enough load on it that it's needing to supplement from its battery, which eventually gets depleted.

Connect up to its management port and see what the logs say.

Oh, and the noises you're hearing? Those are the various relays in the UPS opening and closing.

Comment: While extremely unlikely, it's also possible there might be some problem with the mains voltage (maybe too low, or actually unstable), I think.

Comment: Yes, true. I've seen that exact thing before.

Comment: It's crazy. Even if I disconnect everything from the UPS, it will turn off. So it's it the problem, or the voltage. I need to check this.